# Why is @PreDestroy being invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shutdown-hook

I have a Spring boot app running in docker on ECS

I can see that my @PreDestory method is being invoked on my @Component classes (added to gracefully shutdown an ExecutorService) but even with Trace logging level set I cannot see why. Is there a way to add a shutdown hook that provides information as to what event caused the shutdown to occur.

Comment: The predestroy is called if yoyr application is stopped. Something must be stopping it and I doubt adding additional logging will point that out. You can see the time it stopped and check what happend in your environment. In short check your logs.

Comment: It seems as though the application logs in grafana continue to tick - even though i can see my log statement in predestroy methods (I am just logging that the method was called)

Comment: What is your component? Specifically scoped, if so it will be destroyed if the scope doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I have no defined a scope so would assume it defaulted to singleton

Comment: Please show some code/configuration etc. to see how/where you are using this.